# Audio in Image,Graph or WaveForm Representation

Tags: matlab, audio, speech-recognition, audio-processing, deep-learning

Our task is to feed the audio data into the deep learning tensor flow model in the form of image representation(or graphical,waveform). Question is what is the best way of representing audio in image format??

The representation must focus on words rather than voices.i.e., The similarity of the words must be high than the voices, when two person are speaking the same word.

Comment: There is no way of *"...representing audio in image format"*. The closest you could get to this is the [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) but I would not seriously consider its use as an "image". Do you think you could clarify a bit?

Comment: @A_A Thank you. Considering audio as a 1d array. We  need to represent in a 2d format for the deep learning model to recognize pattern. We tried FFT(spectrogram) but the similarity between the voices is higher than that of the words. Our objective isn't that. Kindly Help. Thank you in advance.